# Trait inheritence details?

Tags: crusader-kings-3

I'm looking at the CK3 Wiki and noticing a few holes, particularly with the trait inheritance logic for "leveled" traits such as Hale / Robust / Herculean. It's clear what happens for normal traits in general cases where one (or both) parents have (either dominant or recessive) or do not have the particular trait. What is less clear are less straight-forward cases. In particular, I am looking for answers to the following set of interrelated<sup>1</sup> questions:

- How do opposite traits interact, e.g. if one parent is Hale and the other is Delicate? This is not discussed at all on the Wiki.
- How do traits of different levels interact? The guide to this interaction on the Wiki is poorly formatted, and missing some numbers.
- When/how are leveled traits "strengthened", going from e.g. Hale to Robust?
- How do all these interact with the "Blood" Dynasty Legacies?

<sub><sup>1</sup>: Like my dynasty...</sub>